# getting "fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type" when trying to read values from an array of class objects

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

There is an issue that i can't understand and can not find an answer to:
i have this method in a tableViewCOntroller that is calling another viewCOntroller with TableView inside it

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowBook" {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let books = categoryStore.allCategories[selectedIndexPath.row].books

            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! BookViewController
            destinationVC.books = books
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the BookViewController i have this just for testing:

```
var books = [Book]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(books[0].name)
}
```

I can see that the books var is an array that is holding books:

```
class Book {
var name: String = ""
var id: Int = -1
var categoryId: Int = -1
var bookAuthor: String = ""
var level1Name: String = ""
var level2Name: String = ""
var level3Name: String = ""
var level4Name: String = ""
var levels: Int = -1
var orderKey: Int = -1
var viewCount: Int = -1
var viewLevel: Int = -1
var chapters: [AnyObject] = []
```

}

so i am getting an array of books with 13 key/value pairs dictionary in the books var

when i'm trying to print any thing, lets say:

```
print(books[0].name)
```

I get the error:

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

and i can't understand why...

p.s The transition is working and i can see the next table but then getting the fatal error

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there are only Book class objects in your array?

Comment: That is what i see then i put a break point and examine the books array, maybe i'm not reading the debugger correctly, but that is what i can see. Added a screen capture of the debugger and code with the break point on the print ( The line the code breaks )

Comment: What does the original storage in `categoryStore.allCategories[selectedIndexPath.row].books` look like? The debugger seems to indicate that you're dealing with dictionaries rather than `Book`s if I'm reading this right. Try printing `books[0]` first rather than accessing the element.

Comment: I don't know how the compiler let you get that far, but you have an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`s.  A dictionary entry is not the same as a `class` instance with 13 properties.

Comment: Try declaring `var books = [[NSObject: AnyObject]]()` and then `print(books[0]["name"]!)`.

Comment: You have declared `books` as an array of `Book` objects but then you have assigned an array of `NSDictionary`. It looks like you need to create an initialiser for `Book` that takes a dictionary and then interate your array of NSDictionaries, creating Books and putting them in an array

Comment: @vacawama when i tried your solution i got a compiler error: Cannot assign value of type '[Book]' to type '[[NSObject : AnyObject]]', so i am guessing that i am getting an array of Books after all, i will try the init thing but from what i understand there is no need for an init function as long as there is no connivance init, i'm suppose to get the free init function, this is so confusing for a begginer

Comment: What are you using to store the data?  Core Data?  Something else?  The problem seems to be earlier because `categoryStore.allCategories[selectedIndexPath.row].books` is returning `[Book]` but that clearly isn't what it contains.

Comment: @sas, The original data source is a very complex JSON i am getting from an API, that holds categories, for each category it hold many things, one of them is the books in that category, so what i am doing is getting each category, and the category object holds also a books array for that category. all that data is connected to the Books  table view controllers row, and when i click on it i can get the books array in the category object that connected to that row, i thought that the NSDictionary is a representation of each book object, but maybe i was wrong...

Comment: Maybe the transition from JSON object to a Book object in the Categories API didn't work... I followed BigNurdRanch tutorial to do that, but maybe i missed something... kind of lost here

Comment: Could you post a link to the tutorial and show the code you wrote?

Comment: fix it, posting an answer, 10x... Stupid beginner problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, This was a beginner problem that might help others.

The scenario: I have a complex JSON: root is object, for each key in the object there is a numeric value (deferent key but the value has the same structure) and the value is the Category Object!
For each category there are many key/Value pairs and one of them is the the Books KEY and the value is array or objects, each one is a book.

The problem: when i deserialised the JSON, i parsed the categories with an array of books, but the books as mentioned in the comments weren't really book instances more array of NSDictionary objects.

So after deserialising the Category i have to add an init method in The Book class to get an NSDictionary and parse it into a Book Object.

After that for each category i have to go over the the NSArray of books and for each one to create an Object go Book and return an Array of Books.

That did the trick and now every thing is working:

API:

```
// Getting NSArray of NSDictionary that represnets books and convert it into Books array
static func getBooksFromArr(booksArr: NSArray) -> [Book] {
    var books = [Book]()

    for book in booksArr {
        let thisBook = Book(bookDict: book as! NSDictionary)
        books.append(thisBook)
        print(book)
    }

    return books
}

// Parsing the category object
private static func CategoryFromJSONObject(json: [String: AnyObject]) -> Category? {
    guard let
        id = json["Id"] as? Int,
        name = json["Name"] as? String,
        booksArr = json["Books"] as? NSArray else {
            return nil
    }

    let books = getBooksFromArr(booksArr)

    return Category(name: name, id: id, books: books)
}
```

Book Class:

```
init(bookDict: NSDictionary){
    self.name = (bookDict["Name"] ?? "") as! String
    self.id = (bookDict["Id"] ?? -1) as! Int
    self.categoryId = (bookDict["CategoryId"] ?? -1) as! Int
    self.bookAuthor = (bookDict["BookAuthor"] ?? "") as! String
    self.level1Name = (bookDict["Level1Name"] ?? "") as! String
    self.level2Name = (bookDict["Level2Name"] ?? "") as! String
    self.level3Name = (bookDict["Level3Name"] ?? "") as! String
    self.level4Name = (bookDict["Level4Name"] ?? "") as! String
    self.levels = (bookDict["Levels"] ?? -1) as! Int
    self.orderKey = (bookDict["OrderKey"] ?? -1) as! Int
    self.viewCount = (bookDict["ViewCount"] ?? -1) as! Int
    self.viewLevel = (bookDict["ViewLevel"] ?? -1) as! Int
    self.chapters = (bookDict["Chapters"] ?? []) as! [AnyObject]
}
```

Now i will have to do the same for the chapters if i want to compose books to hold the chapters.

I didn't write the REST API so don't ask me why they did it as so, but now every thing is working and that is the point of it.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, let's start with your error.

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element
>   type

A swift array is complaining that one of it's elements is not what it's expecting. The NSArray element does not match the swift array element.

Now we know that a NSArray can store different types of elements, for example, NSNumber, NSDictionary, NSString... you get the picture. So clearly our issue here is type related.

Now looking at your segue code we can see that we do not actually state what type books is, we let swift's type inference work it out for us. This is where our first sign of the issue occurs. You are expecting an array of [Book] but for some reason you are getting a type of NSArray.

If you make the change from:

```
let books = categoryStore.allCategories[selectedIndexPath.row].books
let books : [Book] = categoryStore.allCategories[selectedIndexPath.row].books
```

You will now crash at this line, because you are now stating the type expected.

**Full Method:**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowBook" {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let books : [Book] = categoryStore.allCategories[selectedIndexPath.row].books

            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! BookViewController
            destinationVC.books = books
        }
    }
}
```

This is backed up by your debugger console output, it says that you have an array of **13 NSDictionary types.**

This means you need to investigate where you populate the [Book] array - i.e. `categoryStore.allCategories`

Comment: 10x for the direction, i understood it from the comments, and posted the answer with the code to fix this... now every thing is working and i hope it will help other beginner programmers

Comment: thanks - I am slow, there was no answer when I started answering the question :) And yes it was covered in the comments I was just answering it explicitly for the readers that follow after us

Comment: Consider that an annotation `.. : [Book] ...` does **not** cast the type. For example in case `books` is `[AnyObject]` even if it contains only `Book` objects.

Comment: Could add a little more detail to the statement please,  I know it does not cast the type, but it does say what the variable's type will be, right?

Comment: No, in this particular case (an array of dictionaries according to the debug console) the annotation does not "convert" the object to an array of `Book`. Annotations are only useful in a declaration line if the type is ambiguous for example to distinguish `OptionSetType` e.g. (`[.Left, .Center]`) from a standard literal `Array` or to declare a `CGFloat` rather than the default `Double`. In all other cases annotations are syntactic sugar and not really needed.

Comment: I am not expecting to 'convert' anything, I am expecting it to fail to compile because the types differ.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was just casting to the wrong array type in the code above the problem...